# New to Abstract Algebra, need guidance

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning, learning

I am new to Abstract Algebra. How should I begin learning it. On the face if it, it doesn't look easy to me.I have bought the book by Prof. Gallian. Is there any other book or any videos which I can watch? Any other suggestions?

Comment: *Algebra* by M. Artin

Comment: *need guidance* - Maybe [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guide_for_the_Perplexed) might help ?

Comment: Thanks Lucian..Yeah this is the book I was looking for Algebra

Comment: @Vim Thanks.. I will try the book by Artin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book by Gallian contains interesting elementary problems, which a beginner should try, and they are arranged in n increasing order of difficulty; but once we start solving them one-by-one then all are easier.

The other book is "Abstract Algebra-Fraleigh" which contains exercises from elementary level to difficult level. It contains exercises of the kind True-False, which do not trouble too much to a beginner.

In both the books, there are answers to selected problems, so both are good for self study.

The other standard books would be:

-Undergraduate Algebra - Serge Lang

-Abstract Algebra - Dummit and Foot

-Algebra - Serge Lang.

Comment: Thanks..Is there a complete solution manual to Gallian? In case I want to verify my solutions.

Comment: I don't know. But see the link http://www.d.umn.edu/~jgallian/, which contains many resources for study in algebra.

Comment: Thanks mate...I will get started with this, if I have doubts I will post on this forum..